# On the constrution of the Schäffer matrix

Tags: operator-theory

Consider the Hilbert space $H=\oplus \mathcal{H}_{i}$. And the projection $P_{\mathcal{H}}H=\mathcal{H}_{0}$.

Every bounded operator $S$ on $H$ has a matrix representation $(S_{ij})$ whose entries are operators on $\mathcal{H}_{i}$ satisfying $(Sh)_{i}=\sum S_{ij}h_{j}$

The book I am reading(Harmonic analysis of operators on Hilbert space) claims that the above projection implies,

\begin{equation}
P_{\mathcal{H}}Sh=P_{\mathcal{H}}(S_{i0}h)=S_{00}h
\end{equation}
for $h\in \mathcal{H}$

I dont see how we get the second equality, why do we only consider $S_{i0}$ ? It might be their supression of notation that confuses me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $h \in H$ and $S \in B(H)$. I suggest that the index set is $\mathbb{N} = \{0,1,2, ...\}$. The operator $P_{\mathcal{H}_{0}} \colon H \to H$ can be represented as the matrix which has a $1$ at $(0,0)$ and $0$ elsewhere. Hence,

$$P_{\mathcal{H}_{0}} S h = P_{\mathcal{H}_{0}} (\sum_{j} S_{i,j} h_{j})_{i} = (\sum_{j} S_{0,j} h_{j},0,...).$$

If you choose $h=(h_{0},0,...) \in H$ with $h_{0} \in \mathcal{H}_{0}$, you obtain

$$ P_{\mathcal{H}_{0}} S h = (S_{0,0} h_{0},0,...).$$

If you abuse the notation (identifying $\mathcal{H}_{0}$ with $\mathcal{H}_{0}\oplus 0 \oplus 0 ...$ and restricting $P_{\mathcal{H}_{0}}$ to its "image", i.e. $P_{\mathcal{H}_{0}} \colon H \to \mathcal{H}_{0}$), you can conclude that

$$P_{\mathcal{H}_{0}} S h_{0} = S_{0,0} h_{0}.$$

Comment: Thanks I totally missed that $h\in \mathcal{H}$